# MVC3 Actionlink with submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I am new MVC user and I am trying to make shopping cart as following  [MVC Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8)

I am trying to pass the radiobutton value which is different price types through actionlink.
Is it possible to pass the value with productId?
When I click the link, it will call 'AddToCart' method.
Could you help me? thanks.

Product model

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
public class Product
{
    [Key] public int productId { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product model name is required")]
    public String model { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.#}")]
    public decimal displaySize { get; set; }
    public String processor { get; set; }
    public int ramSize { get; set; }
    public int capacity { get; set; }
    public String colour { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public decimal threeDayPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal aWeekPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal twoWeekPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal aMonthPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal threeMonthPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal sixMonthPrice { get; set; }
    //public decimal sixMonthPrice { get { return price * 0.25M; } }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
}
```

details.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Product
<td>
        Rental Period: <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        { 
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, Model.threeDayPrice) 
            3 day: £@Model.threeDayPrice
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, Model.aWeekPrice)
            1 week: £@Model.aWeekPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.twoWeekPrice)
            2 week: £@Model.twoWeekPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.twoWeekPrice)
            1 month: £@Model.twoWeekPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.threeMonthPrice)
            3 month: £@Model.threeMonthPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.sixMonthPrice)
            6 month: £@Model.sixMonthPrice 
            </div>
        }      
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="button" style="margin-left:200px; width:90px;">
    //Is it possible to submit the selected radiobutton value through this?
    @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.productId }, "")
</p>
```

---Added controller---
ShoppingCartController.cs

```
 public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        // Retrieve the product from the database
        var addedProduct = db.Product
            .Single(product => product.productId == id);

        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a submit button instead of an ActionLink. This way all the input values will be sent to the controller when you submit the form:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Product
<td>
    Rental Period: <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.productId }, FormMethod.Post))
    { 
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, Model.threeDayPrice) 
            3 day: £@Model.threeDayPrice
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, Model.aWeekPrice)
            1 week: £@Model.aWeekPrice 
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.twoWeekPrice)
            2 week: £@Model.twoWeekPrice 
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.twoWeekPrice)
            1 month: £@Model.twoWeekPrice 
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.threeMonthPrice)
            3 month: £@Model.threeMonthPrice 
        </div>
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.sixMonthPrice)
            6 month: £@Model.sixMonthPrice 
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
    }      
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I use submit button instead of actionlink, shoppingCartController cannot get int id. It cannot pass the productId. It happens error, 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddToCart(Int32)' in 'MvcApplication2.Controllers.ShoppingCartController''

Comment: @wholee1, then add the id when generating the form: `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.productId }, FormMethod.Post))`. I have updated my answer to illustrate with an example. I have also removed the hidden field which you no longer need.

Comment: Thank you it is passing the productId now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because you say you are new right off the bat I'm going to tell you that the way you are going about this is not the best way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Putting a submit button at the bottom of the form will get the data to post and bind to Product if you change the top of the form to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "WHATEVERYOURCONTROLLERISCALLED"))
```

but I think you are missing a few key points here.

There are some conventions that you seem to be ignoring

ShoppingCart.cs should be named ShoppingCartController.cs and appear in the controllers folder of your project

Instead of naming each price on the model you can use a list of prices options and display them on the form as a series of radio buttons while putting the mutually exclusive choice. for example.

The Model

```
public class Product{

// remove all the different price properties. 

// other properties go here...And while you are at it Use Pascal case for property names Eg. displaySize would be DisplaySize but I guess that is up to you.

[Required]
public string PriceChoice { get; set; }

}
```

The Controller

```
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{

public ActionResult Details(int productId)
{
   // get the product from the database
    var model = Database.GetProductById(productId);

   // set a default if you want
   model.PriceChoice = "a";

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(Product model)
{
    // do whatever you need to do

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.Id });
}
}
```

The View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>A: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PriceChoice , "a")</div>
<div>B: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PriceChoice , "b")</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PriceChoice )
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Now that's all very abridged and basic so I hope you get the gist of it.

Also you'll find some value in reading this [Post Redirect Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) So while it doesn't strictly apply to what you are doing it will explain the structure of the code you are reading in the examples where you see RedirectToAction.

Now if you want to do this really cleverly you will have to learn some javascript and issue an Ajax command.

Hope this helps